# Using d3 v5, in node console and WebStorm, can't get d3.csv() to work

Tags: csv, d3.js, fetch

I've spent the whole day trying to google and read examples of reading a data file with d3.csv() but don't find a really straight answer, not one that works.  This should be simple.

I am using node version 8.10.0
I have done the following:

```
npm install d3
npm install fetch
npm install jsdom
```

I have a local file "data_stacked.csv"

```
group,Nitrogen,normal,stress
banana,12,1,13
poacee,6,6,33
sorgho,11,28,12
triticum,19,6,1
```

I started with this code:

```
var d3 = require("d3");

d3.csv("data_stacked.csv").then (function(data) {
    console.log(data)
});
```

When it executes I get" "ReferenceError: fetch is not defined"
To make a long story short I went down all sorts of rabbit holes involving 'fetch", "jsdom", and a number of other things, none of which worked.

If I add the line

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
```

I get this error output:

```
/home/carl/WebstormProjects/node-project-2/node_modules/webidl-conversions/lib/index.js:357
    } catch {
            ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/carl/WebstormProjects/node-project-2/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:3:27)
```

I tried it with node, with WebStorm, and opening directly in a browser.

The long and the short of it is I just want to be able to get the data from a local CSV file from a javascript program run with node.  I'm hoping to find a brief example of code that just works.  Nothing I find on the googles seems to do that.  If anyone can point me to an example that is a simple but complete piece of code (not a snippet omitting some needed context) I'd greatly appreciate it.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

OK I'm answering my own question here since I understand this better now.

1. The d3.csv()  call should be in the client-side javascript for instance in, or included, in index.html (or whatever hmtl page it's needed on).
2. If you specify a local path, for instance:

```
d3.csv("data.csv").then(
  function(data) { ...});
```

the browser probably will complain (visible in its developer console) with something like "URL scheme must be http or https ..." - this is a security feature.

Easy work-around is to use the simple python server:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer <port> &
```

where  is a port number not reserved for anything else, say maybe 3001, then in the browser address bar enter:

```
localhost:3001
```

On the other hand if you want to use nodejs, in your index.js file add the lines:

```
const dataPath = __dirname + '/data.csv';
app.get ('/data.csv', function(req, res) { res.sendFile(dataPath); });
```

The above assuming you've set up 'app' as an 'express' instance.  Also it appears that the file path in the client side d3.csv() path should be '/data.csv' not just 'data.csv'